# How to get working copy from git repository?

Tags: git

I need to get some files from a git repository.  I can clone the repository, but then I've got a clone of the repository -- not some actual files to work on.

Specifically, when I do

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:example/example.git myfolder
```

I get a clone and also working files in myfolder, but when I do

```
git clone -b OtherBranch --single-branch git@gitlab.com:example/otherexample.git otherfolder
```

... I'm just getting a repository.  It's pretty big, and takes a while to download, but it doesn't put any working files in my working folder.

I don't know why the working set is empty. Is that just telling me about the contents of the repository? If so, what is it telling me?  What are the conditions for "clone" to also do the (logically unrelated) working file creation?

<sub>Unfortunately, when I search for help, I find lots and lots of stuff about git repositories, and lots more stuff about git repositories, and more stuff about repositories. Distributed repositories is a difficult concept that needs explaining, and evidently getting working files is something that "just works" in the normal use case.  Obviously, the documentation must be there, but after reading pages and pages and pages of stuff about fetch <sub>(git is a distributed repository system)</sub> and pull <sub>(git is a distributed repository system)</sub> and checkout <sub>(git is a distributed repository system)</sub> and merge <sub>(git is a distributed repository system)</sub> --- where there is lots of stuff about what's really going on in your repository behind the scenes, and information about creating and cloning and merging repositories, and information about moving things between your local and remote repositories, and the important secondary use cases for common commands  --- I got lost in the sheer volume of background information.</sub>

Comment: "*What are the conditions for "clone" to also do the (logically unrelated) working file creation?*" The conditions are: **1)** there're files in the head (tip) commit of the branch; and **2)** there is no `-n`/`--no-checkout` option in the command line. To debug the situation further could you do `cd otherfolder && git checkout HEAD` ? what is the result?

Comment: Sounds like you want to do a shallow clone (to get a single commit from the repo, instead of getting all of the history of the project) with a sparse checkout (so that you only get a few files in the working tree, instead of the whoooooole list of files on that commit you want to work on).

Comment: Maybe you are supposed to switch to a different branch if the default one is empty. How about `git branch` and switch to one of them.

Comment: @phd Is "git clone" an implicit "git checkout"?  If so, can you construct an answer?  When I was looking, I immediately found material telling me that I could use "git checkout" to change branches, and that it's been split into two commands: switch and restore, and more, not immediately relevant, and assuming a basic level of prior knowledge which I lack.

Comment: @Peter-Krebs maybe I do. Is that what "clone" means in this context? I have a clone of the repository: now I'm trying to get some files to work on.

Comment: clone means to download the whole repository and it would check out its default branch immediately for you. If it does not have a default branch I suppose it leaves your working copy empty. But if it took time to download there is certainly code in some of the branches.

Comment: "*Is "git clone" an implicit "git checkout"?*" Yep. To be precise `git clone URL` is a convenience shortcut for `git init && git remote add origin URL && git fetch origin && git checkout`. Obviously, `git clone --no-checkout` omits the last step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no working directory with a local clone, it is a "bare" repository, or the head of the working branch/revision is empty, or the clone operation has "failed".

"git clone*, by default, includes a subsequent action: ["...clones ... **and** creates and checks out an initial branch"](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

You might consider that if the documentation for the "clone" action has to start with the information that clone *"does 'clone' and also something else"* then perhaps the verb was poorly chosen: that's one point of view.

As is perhaps appropriate for documentation of a *distributed repository* version control system, different versions of the truth exist: an alternative understanding is that, by default, a git repository *includes* a working directory. The working directory is *part of* the repository.

Because the working directory is "part of" a repository, [on this view](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), the "checkout" operation makes a *change to the repository*.

Regarding the three possible reasons for an empty working folder:

- A 'bare' repository has no working directory, but that's almost incidental: a bare repository has no remote parent repository. You create a bare repository on a network server to be the remote parent of a system of local clones.
- git branches aren't normally empty: there is not much requirement for version control of empty branches, and the normal creation process doesn't normally create an empty branch. An empty branch is possible, but unlikely.
- If the clone/checkout operation "fails" there is often some kind of error message, but you may have missed it, or it may have gone only to Standard Error output. The error may be (probably is) quite small and quick compared to the rest of the "clone" operation (select, compress, download).

You can check if the "checkout" part of the operation has failed by running

```
git describe --dirty
```

or

```
git status
```

If only the "checkout" part of "clone" failed, "git describe --dirty" will give you the "commit-id" with the tag "dirty" (the working folder doesn't match the local "head" version): "git status" will list as "deleted" all the missing files that should be in your working folder.

"checkout" can fail for a number of reasons that are essentially unrelated to git: in particular, file system incompatibilities or permission errors.

If you didn't see/missed errors during the "clone" operation, you can run "checkout" again (it will revert/correct the "dirty" branch). Since the operation is not /exactly/ the same as "clone", the /exact/ error(s) may be and will be different.